# language style for complicated text formatting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working in Unity to develop a text engine which will allow some flags and parameters to be set mid-sentence, like color or font; I can't decide on a good language style to use for writing out the dialogue. It should be noted that the default Rich Text in unity won't do, as it needs custom tags.

So far I've considered a BBCode and XML style formats. Are there any alternatives which might be better suited to something like this? Examples of how they'd look would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The unity text component natively supports bold, italic, size and color.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html

Comment: Unfortuently it's more advanced than just the default text styles, and I needs custom parameters. I've edited the question to reflect this.